# Slowing down animation in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, animation, bezier

I have a class project that uses Windows Forms to create a GUI that controls a second form. The second form is a DrawingForm with a bitmap. Using a backgroundworker, I am drawing random, continuous Bezier curves all over the bitmap. It is a simple program, so it is able to draw them quickly, hundreds per second. I would like to add a slider bar that would allow me to control how fast the lines paint. In other words, I dont want to set up each curve to be drawn on a timer, which would cause it to appear to stop and start hundreds of times a second. I have exhausted myself searching google, any tips on how to do this would be awesome. Thanks!

Edit: Here is a code snippet. This code is in my class for my drawing form. Its constructor is called from my main GUI/user control class.

```
    // this is the code executed by the background thread
    // it can run continously without hanging the user interface thread
    // except that it draws to a bitmap (with the bMapDC) instead of to the form
    private void backgroundWorkerDrawing_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            if (scribbleOn == true)
            {
                curveColor = changeColor(curveColor);
                Pen pen = new Pen(curveColor, penThickness);

                if (i == 0) // initial curve should start in center, the rest of the points will be random
                {
                    lastX = GUI.rand.Next(0, bMapWidth); //used to store the x coordinate where the curve ends
                    lastY = GUI.rand.Next(0, bMapHeight); //used to store the y coordinate where the curve ends

                    bMapDC.DrawBezier(pen, initialX, initialY, GUI.rand.Next(0, bMapWidth), GUI.rand.Next(0, bMapHeight),
                    GUI.rand.Next(0, bMapWidth), GUI.rand.Next(0, bMapHeight), lastX, lastY);
                }

                if (i > 0) // used for all curves after the first one. 
                {
                    int tempX = GUI.rand.Next(0, bMapWidth); //used to store the x coordinate where the curve ends
                    int tempY = GUI.rand.Next(0, bMapHeight); //used to store the y coordinate where the curve ends

                    bMapDC.DrawBezier(pen, lastX, lastY, GUI.rand.Next(0, bMapWidth), GUI.rand.Next(0, bMapHeight),
                    GUI.rand.Next(0, bMapWidth), GUI.rand.Next(0, bMapHeight), tempX, tempY);

                    lastX = tempX; // sets the last x coordinate of the last curve for next loop
                    lastY = tempY;  // sets the last y coordinate of the last curve for next loop
                }
                pen.Dispose(); // free up resources from the pen object
            }   
            else i = 0;
        }
    }

    // timer event handler causes the form to be repreatedly invalidated
    // This causes the paint event handler to keep going off,
    // which causes the bMap that is continously being drawn to
    // by the background thread to be continously redisplayed in the form.
    // We will see other ways to do this that may be better.
    private void timerInvalidate_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void DrawingForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lock (bMap)
        {
            bMapHeight = bMap.Height;  // set the vars that keep track of the size of the bMap
            bMapWidth = bMap.Width;

            initialX = bMapWidth / 2; // start the curve at the center of the bMap
            initialY = bMapHeight / 2;
            bMapDC = Graphics.FromImage(bMap);  // setup the DC (device context) to allow drawing to the bMap)
            backgroundWorkerDrawing.RunWorkerAsync();   // start the background thread
            timerInvalidate.Enabled = true;  // start the timer that will cause periodic Invalidates
        }
    }
```

Comment: a code snippet might help. Exactly how are you performing the drawing and are you drawing a complete line before you move onto the new curve to paint? If you can, post up the code from the how you are applying them to the bmp, how you are generating the curves in the background worker

Answer (score 0):

You can make thread and use sleep

```
private Thread SimulaciaArts;
public Animation(){
public SpleepValue { get; set;}

SimulaciaArts = new Thread(new ThreadStart(simuluj));
}

public void simuluj(){

//anything
Thread.Sleep(SleepValue);

}
```

and in gui you must use delegate

```
 delegate void Invoker();
 private void setSpeed()
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new Invoker(setSpeed));
                return;
            }
 Simulation.SleepValue=Speed;
}
```

Hope it is good.

Comment: sleeping is never the solution! :)